# SciTE Script - How to get inside a Tree Control to set checkboxes

Tags: autoit, scite

I'm using AutoIt and SciTE to create an installation script.  The problem I am running into is that there is a tree menu for selection of features.  I can select the whole treeview (SysTreeView32), but am not sure how to get inside it to check the boxes without doing a mouse move and click (not a great option).

The Treeview looks like this:

[image: Treeview Image]

The Control Info from AutoIT is like this:

[image: Control Info]

I'm sure it is possible, just can't figure out how to do it.  This is my first attempt a such a script.  Creating a response file does not work for this exe for some reason.  So - this appears to be my only way out to create a somewhat silent install (not silent anymore, but at least automated).

*** EDIT -  Current State of Things ***

I did figure out how to do some of this, but I still can't figure out if the items is selected before accessing it.  So - since it toggles, I could be turning off a feature I want!

```
$hWnd = WinWaitActive($WindowTitle, 'Select Features')
$tvCtl = ControlGetHandle($WindowTitle, '', 'SysTreeView321')

$firstItem = _GUICtrlTreeView_FindItem($tvCtl, 'eBooks')
_GUICtrlTreeView_SelectItem($tvCtl, $firstItem, $TVGN_FIRSTVISIBLE)
_GUICtrlTreeView_ClickItem($tvCtl, $firstItem, "left", True, 1)

Send('{SPACE}')
```

I wouldn't think I would have to send the space since I sent the ClickItem, but seems so.

I could also do this:

```
ControlTreeView($hWnd, '', $tvCtl, 'Select', '#0')
ControlSend($hWnd, '', $tvCtl, ' ')
```

That will toggle the first one.  So - i can count them all up and do it that way.

But when I check for "IsEnabled" or "IsChecked", it always says NO.  So - I can't check the ones I need only.  I have to hope their status is what I expect.

Here is how I am checking "IsChecked" and "IsEnabled":

```
If ControlCommand($hWnd, '', $logTool, 'IsEnabled') then
    ConsoleWrite('Log Tool - IsEnabled' & @CRLF)
Else
    ConsoleWrite('Log Tool - NOTEnabled' & @CRLF)
EndIf
```

and

```
If ControlCommand($hWnd, '', $logTool, 'IsChecked') then
    ConsoleWrite('Log Tool - IsChecked' & @CRLF)
Else
    ConsoleWrite('Log Tool - NOTChecked' & @CRLF)
EndIf
```

It always comes back NOTEnabled and NOTChecked.  I made sure that I ran the same procedure above:  FindItem, SelectItem, ClickItem.  And, the correct item is highlighted/selected when this procedure is run - I can see that.  So - it just isn't returning a proper value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Opt('WinTitleMatchMode', 2)
$hWnd = WinGetHandle("InstallShield Wizard") ; Notice the correct title
$hTree = ControlGetHandle($hWnd, '', "[CLASS:SysTreeView32;INSTANCE:1]")

; == Now you can interact with the treeview with functions from "GuiTreeView.au3"
```

EDIT:

Try this

```
; Select the item so: 
_GUICtrlTreeView_SelectItem($hTree, $hItem, $TVGN_CARET)

; Get checked state: 
_GUICtrlTreeView_GetChecked($hTree, $hItem)
```

For more deatails read the AutoIt help.

Comment: I do have similar to that (now) after hours of attempts - I'll post the edit above.  I don't like that I can't determine if it is 'checked'.  Otherwise, I could accidentally de-select something. :(